# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if $n^{5}-1$ is prime then $n=2$.

Tags: proof-writing

I should show $n^{5}-1= (n-1) \left( n^{4}+n^{3}+n^{2}+n+1\right)$ prime. So, how?

*Proof trying.* We know $\left( n^{4}+n^{3}+n^{2}+n+1\right)$ is odd.

Comment: If $n > 2$, then $n^5-1$ is divisible by $(n-1) > 2$, so $n^5-1$ would not be prime. Therefore, for $n^5-1$ to be prime, $n=2$ (which we see that $31$ is divisible by $2$).

Comment: That factorization of $n^5-1$ is all you need to know. What is $n-1$ if $n>2$? The latter factor is an even bigger number, so the product can't possibly be prime.

Comment: You can try proving the contrapositive of the statement. If "n" is not equal to two then $n^{5} -1$ will not be prime. This is easy to prove due the way you factored $n^{5} -1$.

Comment: Why $\left( n-1\right) >2$?

Comment: @user2825632 Why $(n-1)>2$, why not $(n-1)>1$?

Comment: You're right - it should have been $(n-1) \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n^m-1$ is divisible by $n-1$ for all natural numbers $m, n\ge 2$.  Proceed from there.